# i am stuck at this query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

how can I display same column twice in a table but with different data using sql?

I have 3 tables `tbstu, tbexm, tbscr`

```
tbstu = stucod int PK, stunam var(100)

tbexm = exmcod int PK, exmnam var(100)

tbscr = scrcod int PK, scrsub var(100), scrach int 
scrstucod int FK (to table tbstu)
screxmcod int FK (to table tbexm)

qry = 
  select scrcod, screxmcod, scrstucod, scrsub, scrach, scrach 
  from tbscr, tbstu, tbexm
  where scrstucod = stucod 
  and screxmcod = exmcod 
  and stucod = 101 
  and exmcod = 1001
```

now I want the second `scrach` in select to display data with respect to `exmcod=1002` and Total columns to sum scrach and scrach

Comment: What you've posted is not valid C# nor valid SQL. Please post your actual code.

Comment: you will probably need to use either subqueries or multiple queries into temp tables/cte with a final select. Not too sure with the code you have provided.

Comment: Can you put actual code and sample data?, what if you have multiple results satisfying  "stucod = 101 and exmcod =1001" ?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the relevant data, and what you would like it to look like ?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly,

Use Left Join:

```
    select
      tbscr1.scrcod,
      tbscr2.scrcod ,
      tbscr1.screxmcod,
      tbscr2.screxmcod,
      tbscr1.scrstucod
      tbscr2.scrstucod,
      tbscr1.scrsub,
      tbscr2.scrsub
      tbscr1.scrach,
      tbscr2.scrach,
      tbscr1.scrach+tbscr2.scrach AS Total
from tbstu,tbexm
    left join
      tbscr as tbscr1 on tbscr1.scrstucod =tbstu.stucod and tbscr1.screxmcod = tbexm.exmcod and tbstu.stucod = 101 and tbexm.exmcod =1001
    left join
      tbscr as tbscr2 on tbscr2 .scrstucod =tbstu.stucod and tbscr2 .screxmcod = tbexm.exmcod and tbstu.stucod = 101 and tbexm.exmcod =1002
```

you can also try:

```
select scrcod ,
      screxmcod,
      scrstucod,
      scrsub,
      scrach,
      (select scrach from tbscr ,tbstu,tbexm  
        where scrstucod =stucod and screxmcod = exmcod and stucod = 101 and exmcod =1002) AS scrach2
from tbscr ,tbstu,tbexm  
where scrstucod =stucod and screxmcod = exmcod and stucod = 101 and exmcod =1001
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood, I think this you want to get the following for a given student:

- exam information for two exams (1001 and 1002)
- total score of the two exams

If that's correct, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
  sc1.scrcod, sc1.screxmcod, sc1.scrsub, sc1.scrach,
  sc2.scrcod, sc2.screxmcod, sc2.scrsub, sc2.scrach,
  COALESCE(sc1.scrach, 0) + COALESCE(sc2.scrach, 0) AS TotalScore
FROM tbstu st
LEFT JOIN tbscr sc1 ON st.stucod = sc1.scrstucod AND sc1.screxmcod = 1001 -- Exam 1 info
LEFT JOIN tbscr sc2 ON st.stucod = sc2.scrstucod AND sc2.screxmcod = 1002 -- Exam 2 info
WHERE st.stucod = 101 -- Only get info for student 101
```

**Update**
Based on your comments it looks like you want to also split the exam scores based on subject (`scrsub`).  You can just add this field to your `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT
  st.stucod, 
  sc1.scrsub, 
  sc1.scrach, 
  sc2.scrach, 
  COALESCE(sc1.scrach,0) + COALESCE(sc2.scrach,0) AS TotalScore
FROM tbstu st
LEFT JOIN tbscr sc1 -- Exam 1 info
  ON st.stucod = sc1.scrstucod AND sc1.screxmcod = 1001
LEFT JOIN tbscr sc2 -- Exam 2 info
  ON st.stucod = sc2.scrstucod AND sc2.screxmcod = 1002 AND sc1.scrsub = sc2.scrsub
WHERE st.stucod = 101 -- Only get info for student 101
```

As coded, this query makes a few assumptions:

- this will only work for exams 1001 and 1002
- exam 1001 and 1002 have identical `scrsub` entries (i.e. 4 rows for each exam)

Let me know how that one works.

Comment: output form this is giving 4 times the data which is repetitive too

Comment: Assuming `stucod` is the PK of `tbstu` then that means that the same student took an exam multiple times (i.e. two rows for exam 1001 or exam 1002 for student 101 in the `tbscr` table).  If that's the case, then please specify exactly what you want your output to be.  For example, do you want to only include the most recent exam if a student took the same exam multiple times?

Comment: stucod is PK of tbstu and the same student took two exams exmcod  = 1001 and 1002 but the subjects for the both exam are same (4 subjects that is) but with different scrach w.r.t exmcod                                           in the output i need chosen stucod column once only ans scrsub once only scrach twice w.r.t 1001,1002 and total of both scarch

Comment: i have total of 16 records for two stucod 101,102 for 101, 8 records with the only difference being screxmcod i.e for exam 1001 4 records of same four subjects and for 1002 4 records of same subject , what the above query is doing is displaying 16 records instead of 8 which should be 4-4 horizontally,                            _ here is the Gdrive link to see the required o/p and result from above query           https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17p3d1WXMppndIq1bXf6EwShLWBrh-IsC

Comment: OK, those screenshots help a lot.  It looks like you want to get the exam scores broken down by subject as well `(hindi, english, maths, computer)` correct?  If that's the case, then just add `scrsub` as an extra join condition.  See the updated query (will post soon).

Comment: Great, glad it works.  Do you have any questions or does it make sense?

Comment: why did you use COALESCE instead of sc1.scrach+sc2.scrach

Comment: and can you take a look at this post as well i am stuck at this    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57935946/displaying-data-in-dropdownlist-using-sql-with-querystring

Comment: I put the `COALESCE` in case there is a `NULL` value for either `sc1.scrach` or `sc2.scrach`.  If either of those are `NULL` then the whole expression will return `NULL` regardless of the other value.  You may or may not need it, but it's there just in case.

Comment: Sure I added some ideas to your other post.

Comment: i have a question about this , what if i don't want to use static values of 'exmcod' but the result of the query must remain the same. what should i change

Comment: If you want to pass in the `exmcod` value as a parameter, you can convert the query to a macro or a stored procedure / function (depending on your DBMS - MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) and parameterize this value.  Or do you want to return the result set for all all exam codes?  If that's the case, then it will be a little more complicated based on your model.