# displaying data in dropdownlist using sql with querystring

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have three tables:

1. tbprd -- prdcod int PK, prdtit v(100), prddefuom int FK to prduomcod (tbprduom)
2. tbuom -- uomcod int PK, uomnam v(100)
3. tbprduom -- prduomcod int PK, prduomprdcod int FK prdcod(tbprd), prduomuomcod int FK uomcod(tbuom)

What I need is to display `uomnam` in `dropdownlist` display field and `uomcod` in data value field from `prdcod` which I have passed through query string but if the chosen `prdcod` is 4 then the `dropdownlist` should display all the `uomnam` matching w.r.t all matching `prdtit`

Query I am using:

```
select uomcod, uomnam 
from tbuom, tbprd, tbprduom 
where prdcod = 4 
and prduomuomcod = uomcod 
and prddefprduomcod = prduomcod
```

Look at the images for more clearer idea about what I want and table data

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17p3d1WXMppndIq1bXf6EwShLWBrh-IsC?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand, you want to get all products that have the same title as the product with the given `prdcod`.  If that's correct, then here's one way to do it:

1. Write a query to get the `prdtit` value for `prdcod = 4` (return one column from one row):

```sql
SELECT prdtit 
FROM ...
```

2. Use this value to filter the rest of the rows in the `tbprd` table:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tbrpd
WHERE prdtit = (<Query in Step 1>)
```

3. Add two joins to the `tbprduom` and `tbuom` tables to Step #2 to get the remaining info:

```sql
SELECT tbuom.uomcod, tbuom.uomnam
FROM tbrpd
WHERE prdtit = (<Query in Step 1>)
LEFT JOIN tbprduom ON ... <PK/FK fields) -- Get uomcod for products
LEFT JOIN tbuom ON ... <PK/FK fields) -- Get "uom" fields to return
```

Give it a try and see how far you get.  If you get stuck on a step, just let me know.

Comment: sorry for the late response , had been busy for 4 days ----i just tried this and it works but, I can't quite understand the 3rd step

Comment: No problem.  In the third step, you are just retrieving the extra information you need related to each product.  `LEFT JOIN tbprduom` gets you the "UOM code" associated with each product.  You then use that same "UOM code" to do a `LEFT JOIN` to the `tbuom` table to retrieve the related "UOM" info.  `tbprdum` seems to be a relationship table that associates a product with its UOM info.